# Is there a way to work with information protection of office365 in Microsoft APIs? ideally graphql

Tags: graphql, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-information-protection

My organisation is implementing a solution that require the information protection from
microsoft graphql api.

We're trying to fetch policies and labels in order to:

- add label
- apply/publish label (label policy)

Is it possible to achieve that with the api?

Answer (score 0):

For API reference please go through the below article ->

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/informationprotectionlabel?view=graph-rest-beta

This article nicely describes the information protection label that details how to properly apply a sensitivity label to information. The informationProtectionLabel resource describes the configuration of sensitivity labels that apply to a user or tenant.

Also you can try using Microsoft Graph Security API for information protection->
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/security-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#information-protection

The Microsoft Graph threat assessment API helps organizations to assess the threat received by any user in a tenant. This empowers customers to report spam emails, phishing URLs or malware attachments they receive to Microsoft. The policy check result and rescan result can help tenant administrators understand the threat scanning verdict and adjust their organizational policy.

Other doc for ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/information-protection-overview

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!
We managed to find a way to get labels for a given user from the api [GET /me/informationProtection/policy/labels ] but we can't retrieve them for the organisation the api [GET /informationProtection/policy/labels] return an error without a message;
Also we're stuck in finding a way to automatically apply label to information, any clue ?

Comment: Thanks for getting back!! Please verify the that permissions required for this call are correctly granted.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/informationprotectionlabel-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions. If you still get the error, kindly send the error details  like the request id and the time stamp.

Comment: In this doc, you'll find an example on how to configure an existing Azure Information Protection label to automatically apply the Do Not Forward protection setting.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/quickstart-label-dnf-protectedemail. Hope it helps

Comment: Thx a lot @RB-2902 we were able to retrieve informations with the right permission; but for applying these labels we want to do it using the graph api and we're still missing that point.

Comment: I am also looking for an API to apply labels do documents in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64713411/how-to-apply-a-sensitivity-label-to-a-document-in-sharepoint-online-programmatic). So far the only option I have found is to use MIP SDK, download the file, apply a label and upload the file back. It has many drawbacks but works.